# Show another component on click of button in present component and hide hide the past component completely

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and I want to display a diff component on click of button in the present component and should only show the new component

So I want to display only new component instaead of past component with button

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering on your component `{booleanValue && (<MyComponent />)}`. And only show it if the value returns a `truthy` value.

I'll post a simple example below.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
  const handleShowClick = () => {
    setShow(true);
  }
  
  const handleToggleClick = () => {
    setShow((prevValue) => !prevValue);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!show && (<button onClick={handleShowClick}>Show Component</button>)}
      {show && (<MyComponent />)}
    </div>
  )
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hi. I'm being rendered</h1>
  )
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: The thing is I have 2 different components in which I have button in one component on click of that button I want to display the other component completely I don't even want the button or text of the past component in the example u have shared the buttons are still appearing after the new component is getting displayed

Comment: I edited my answer following your comment

Comment: I'm confused. Didn't you just said that you had 2 components (component with a button on it, and a second one). When the user clicked on the button (belonging to the 1st component) the 2nd should appear and the 1st should hide. Isn't that your problem?

Comment: As for the display it is working fine but when I tried to enter details in the new component showing props.onDirty is not a function as I have used props in that component how to resolve this

Comment: That's a different question that you can ask anew on stackoverflow. It's good to hear that your 1st problem was solved :D